# Is there a way to open new fresh tab with middle clicking on tab bar?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

Is there...? This way is faster than pressing CTRL+T guys. I did it at Opera before but i can't do it now. They just remove that usage. I am using Chrome now btw.

I looked for extension but i couldn't find.